# Saving drawn images in a PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I created a form with a PictureBox. I created a drawing in the PictureBox. But I can't save the file to a specified folder without dialogue controls. Only through code. Please help me if any one knows a solution for this problem. Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

if you drawing in picture box you must convert drawing in bmp format with this code:

```
'Save as BMP-file
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(picturebox1.Width, picturebox1.Height)
draw.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, picturebox1.Width, picturebox1.Height))
bmp.Save("D:\output.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
bmp.Dispose()
```

with this code you can print & save drawing on picturebox object

Comment: I think by 'draw' you meant 'picturebox1'

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox has an Image property of type System.Drawing.Image which you use to get or set the image that the PictureBox represents. System.Drawing.Image has a Save method which will write the image to the specified filename or stream. Is this information OK or do you need more; your question was a little unclear.